# NodeJs + Promise wrapped in a function

Tags: node.js

I am very green with NodeJs, I am trying to make a call to function that makes a promise call, problem is in this scenario, recordId is always returned as undefined, prior to making the API. What am I doing wrong here?

```
var recordId = checkZoneRecord(zoneId, zoneName, dnsRecord);
console.log('Record id: %s', recordId)
if (recordId == ""){
  // record doesn't exist, create new record
  createZoneRecord (zoneId, zoneName, dnsRecord)
}else{
  console.log ('Record name \'%s\' exists for zone \'%s\'', dnsRecord.name, zoneName);
}

function checkZoneRecord(zoneId, zoneName, dnsRecord){

  // check if zone exists
  cf.dnsRecords.browse(zoneId).then(function(resp){
    console.log ('Checking if record name \'%s\' exists in zone \'%s\'', dnsRecord.name, zoneName);
    var data = resp.result;
    var rec = Enumerable.from(data).where(function(x){return x.name == dnsRecord.name + '.' + zoneName}).select(function(i){return i.id}).toJoinedString();
    return rec;
  }).catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two major things causing your code to fail:

1. Your `checkZoneRecord` function never uses `return` (and functions with no `return` will result in `undefined` by default)
2. You're not waiting for your `checkZoneRecord()` call to finish before using the value of `recordId`

Fixing #1 is easy! Make sure to use `return`:

```
function checkZoneRecord(zoneId, zoneName, dnsRecord){

  // The only difference is to add "return" on this next line:
  return cf.dnsRecords.browse(zoneId).then(function(resp){
    /* ... */
    return rec;
  }).catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Fixing #2 is also easy, but we'll need to change things around a bit. When the following code runs, you think you're logging the "record id", but what you're really logging is the "promise of a record id to be resolved some time in the future":

```
var recordId = checkZoneRecord(zoneId, zoneName, dnsRecord);
console.log('Record id: %s', recordId)
```

A better name for the `recordId` variable would be `recordIdPromise`. Fortunately once we have the promise of a value, moving to the value itself is quite simple! There are two ways to get the actual value:

```
// First, using `then`:
let recordIdPromise = checkZoneRecord(zoneId, zoneName, dnsRecord);
recordIdPromise.then(recordId => {
  console.log(recordId);
});
```

```
// Second, using `await`.
// This looks easier, but the caveat is that this code will only work inside of an `async` function.
let recordIdPromise = checkZoneRecord(zoneId, zoneName, dnsRecord);
let recordId = await recordIdPromise;
```

It's worth mentioning that the above snippet can be simplified to:

```
let recordId = await checkZoneRecord(zoneId, zoneName, dnsRecord);
```

Here's how your code could look, fixed up entirely:

```
// Define all your logic in an `async` function called "app":
let app = async () => {

  let recordIdPromise = checkZoneRecord(zoneId, zoneName, dnsRecord);
  let recordId = await recordIdPromise;
  console.log('Record id: %s', recordId)

  if (recordId == ""){
    // record doesn't exist, create new record
    createZoneRecord(zoneId, zoneName, dnsRecord)
  } else {
    console.log ('Record name \'%s\' exists for zone \'%s\'', dnsRecord.name, zoneName);
  }

};

// Define `checkZoneRecord`:
let checkZoneRecord = (zoneId, zoneName, dnsRecord) => {

  // check if zone exists
  return cf.dnsRecords.browse(zoneId).then(function(resp){
    console.log ('Checking if record name \'%s\' exists in zone \'%s\'', dnsRecord.name, zoneName);
    var data = resp.result;
    var rec = Enumerable.from(data).where(function(x){return x.name == dnsRecord.name + '.' + zoneName}).select(function(i){return i.id}).toJoinedString();
    return rec;
  }); // I recommend you don't catch the err in this scope - let it propagate instead!

}

// Call `app`:
app().catch(err => console.log('An error occured', err));
```

Comment: Learned quite a bit from this answer, thank you for taking the time to explain all of this. I like your idea of propagating the exception as well.